# Cor Background da ListView em zebra

Tags: android, android-adapter

Tenho um layout com dois EditText e um ImageView que vai ser adicionada ao ListView através de BaseAdapter.
Pretendia alternar em zebra a cor background da ListView.
O problema é que se a ListView possuir mais do 9 listas o efeito zebra começa a funcionar erradamente.
Para alternar a cor da ListView estou a utilizar a formula:

```
if(position % 2 == 0){
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julgo que você está a usar o chamado *"View holder pattern"* e está a reutilizar as *Views* recorrendo ao *LayoutInflater* apenas quando o parâmetro  `convertView` do método `getView()` do *Adapter* é `null`.

Assim sendo, como você só atribui a cor ao *backgroud* quando a posição é par, quando reutiliza uma *View* que anteriormente era par numa posição ímpar esta mantém a cor `YELLOW`.

Para que a alternância de cor funcione nestes casos terá também de atribuir a cor ao *background* quando a posição for ímpar:

```
if(position % 2 == 0){
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
else{
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DasLinhasÍmpares);
}
```

**Nota:**
O problema só se verifica quando há mais de 9 linhas porque esse deve ser o número de linhas que cabem na tela. Ao fazer *scroll* as *Views* das linhas que deixam de ser visíveis passam a poder ser reaproveitadas pelo *Adapter* e o problema começa.

Comment: Olá ramaral! Era esse o problema. Funcionou. Obrigado.