# Alterar a cor Background da ListView quando o valor chave for encontrado

Tags: android, android-adapter

Na minha app tenho uma `ListView` que é prenchida através de `BaseAdapter`.
Então no `BaseAdapter` eu tenho uma intrução IF para alterar o Background da lista quando do valor de uma variavel foi igual ao valor de uma outra variavel global.
O problema é o `BaseAdapter` altera a cor quando os valores das duas variaveis são iguais (isto só acontece uma única vez) e também altera a cor em outros locais errados!!!??? Aqui vai o código do método `getView` para ver se alguém me consegue ajudar:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewholder;

    if(convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_personalizado_dialog, null);

        viewholder = new ViewHolder();

        viewholder.estacao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewholder.horas = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        view.setTag(viewholder);

    } else {

        viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    String estacaoHora = lista.get(position);
    String[] tokens = estacaoHora.split("/");

    String valor1 = tokens[0];// Estação
    String valor2 = tokens[1];// Hora
    String valor3 = tokens[2];// Minutos

    // Quando o valor da variavel "valor1" for igual ao valor da variavel "estacaoPesquisa" altera a cor de Background:
    if (valor1.equals(estacaoPesquisa)){

        // Altera a cor de fundo da lista:
        viewholder.estacao.setBackgroundColor(contexto.getResources().getColor(R.color.verde_5));
        viewholder.horas.setBackgroundColor(contexto.getResources().getColor(R.color.verde_5));

        viewholder.estacao.setText("  " + valor1);
        viewholder.horas.setText(valor2 + ":" + valor3);

    } else {

        viewholder.estacao.setText("  " + valor1);
        viewholder.horas.setText(valor2 + ":" + valor3);

    }

    return view;
}

// Classe interna:
static class ViewHolder {

    TextView estacao;
    TextView horas;

}
```

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61057/2541) talvez ajude.

Comment: Olá ramaral! O post que indicou é meu. Aqui o meu pedido de ajuda é diferente, ou seja, eu não necessito de fazer uma lista zebrada, eu quero antes fazer uma lista normal mas quando o valor String de uma dada lista for igual ao valor de uma variavel quero alterar a cor de Background dessa lista (que vai ser unica na ListView)...

Comment: Não tinha reparado que o poste era seu. O problema aqui surge pela mesma razão. Vejo que não percebeu o problema. Vou postar uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado ramaral. Fico aguardar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema aqui surge pela mesma razão da sua outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61050/2541).

O Android, para que não seja necessário estar sempre a fazer o *inflate* da view de cada uma das linhas da *ListView*, tem um mecanismo que permite reaproveitar *views* já não utilizadas.
Quando existe um *view* que pode ser reaproveitada ela é passada no parâmetro `convertView` do método `getView()`. Repara que o seu código so faz o *inflate* quando a `convertView` é nula:

```
if(convertView == null){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_personalizado_dialog, null);

    viewholder = new ViewHolder();

    viewholder.estacao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    viewholder.horas = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    view.setTag(viewholder);

} else {

    viewholder = (ViewHolder) ViewHolder.getTag();
}
```

Adicionalmente, para não ter de estar sempre a obter as referencias aos elementos da *view*, através de `findViewById`, é utilizada uma classe, a `ViewHolder`, para guardar essas referências. A `ViewHolder` é guardada na propriedade *Tag* da *View*.

Quando a `convertView` não é nula recuperam-se a `ViewHolder` recorrendo-se ao método `getTag`:

```
.....
.....
} else {

    viewholder = (ViewHolder) ViewHolder.getTag();
}
```

Quando a *view* é reaproveitada ela vem com as sua propriedades *setadas* com os valores usados anteriormente.
Assim como você atribui os valores correspondentes à linha actual,

```
viewholder.estacao.setText("  " + valor1);
viewholder.horas.setText(valor2 + ":" + valor3);
```

tem também de repor qualquer atributo que tenha sido alterado.
Neste caso você altera a cor do *background*:

```
viewholder.estacao.setBackgroundColor(contexto.getResources().getColor(R.color.verde_5));
viewholder.horas.setBackgroundColor(contexto.getResources().getColor(R.color.verde_5));
```

O código terá de ser alterado para que, quando a `estacaoPesquisa` não for a pretendida, seja atribuída a cor "original" do *background*.

```
if (valor1.equals(estacaoPesquisa)){

    // Altera a cor de fundo da lista:
    viewholder.estacao.setBackgroundColor(contexto.getResources().getColor(R.color.verde_5));
    viewholder.horas.setBackgroundColor(contexto.getResources().getColor(R.color.verde_5));

    viewholder.estacao.setText("  " + valor1);
    viewholder.horas.setText(valor2 + ":" + valor3);

} else {

    viewholder.estacao.setBackgroundColor(contexto.getResources().getColor(R.color.????));
    viewholder.horas.setBackgroundColor(contexto.getResources().getColor(R.color.????));

    viewholder.estacao.setText("  " + valor1);
    viewholder.horas.setText(valor2 + ":" + valor3);

}
```

Nota: Substitua `R.color.????` pela cor "original"

Comment: Era esse o problema!! Efetivamente eu não tinha intendido bem a lógica do funcionamento do método getView. Foi excelente a sua explicação. Muito obrigado. Abraço.