# ListView perde estado das linhas durante scroll

Tags: android, listview, rolamento

Possuo uma `ListView` e nele utilizo o seguinte layout para o adapter:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLocal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="question"
        android:textColor="@color/app_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="question"
        android:textColor="@color/app_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainerLikeDislike"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAnswer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/app_blue"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llContainerButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llLike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivLike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/background_btn_like" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvHelped"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Helped"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNumLike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llDisLike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivDisLike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/background_btn_dislike" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNotHelp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Not Help"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNumDisLike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

QA class:

```
public class QA {

    private int id;
    private String question, answer, answer_at, state, city, name;
    public enum state { like, dislike };
    private long up_votes_count, down_votes_count;
    private boolean visible, like, wasVoted;

    // get and setters

}
```

No caso o llContainer (`LinearLayout`) deve receber um evento de click e apresentar o `LinearLayout` llContainerLikeDislike, como uma lista expansiva. Controlar se llContainerLikeDislike esta com seu `Visibility Gone` passa para `Visible` e vice versa. Utilizo este método para isso:

```
public static void expand(final View v, final ListView lv, final int position) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();

            //Moves the listview scroll so that the expanding area is visible.
            lv.setSelectionFromTop(position, v.getLayoutParams().height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}

public static void collapse(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

No `Adapter` uso um `ViewHolder` para controlar a referência de cada linha com o `setTag()` e `getTag()`. No caso cada linha esta mantendo corretamente os dados do objeto qa durante o scroll.
Porém o scroll esta alterando o comportamento das linhas que controlo a expansão e retração das linhas e, habilitação e desabilitação de uma linha que teve seu `ImageView` selecionado.
Utilizo os `ImageView`'s como se fosse botões  para dar um like ou dislike em uma linha, quando clicada fica desabilitada e muda a aparência.
Resumindo, os dados de cada linha estão corretos para os objetos qa mas o dos componentes como linha `Visibility Gone/Visible` e, mudança de cor, habilitar e desabilitar durante o scroll da `ListView` estão de comportamento errado. 
Se uma linha por exemplo de posição 0 esta `Visible`, desabilitado, e mudou a cor, ao mover o scroll da `ListView` uma linha random mais abaixo apresenta o mesmo estado da linha 0.
Usei o debug e os métodos estão recebendo a referência corretamente e, estão sendo chamados somente uma vez, não há repetição para as linhas random.

Segue `getView()` do adapter:

```
public class QAAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QA> implements Filterable {

    private List<QA>filteredData;

    private ArrayList<QA> arrayQA;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Activity activity;

    public QAAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<QA> arrayQA) {
        super(activity, 0);

        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.arrayQA = arrayQA;
        this.filteredData = arrayQA; 
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pergunta, parent,
                false);

        Typeface tfLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Oswald-Light.ttf");

        Typeface tfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf");

        holder.tvAjudou = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvAjudou);
        holder.tvNaoAjudou = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvNaoAjudou);

        holder.tvLocal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocal);
        holder.tvLocal.setTypeface(tfLight);

        holder.tvQuestion = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
        holder.tvQuestion.setTypeface(tfBold);

        holder.tvAnswer = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvAnswer);
        holder.tvAnswer.setTypeface(tfLight);

        holder.tvNumLike = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvNumLike);
        holder.tvNumLike.setTypeface(tfLight);

        holder.tvNumDisLike = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvNumDisLike);
        holder.tvNumDisLike.setTypeface(tfLight);

        holder.ivLike = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivLike);

        holder.ivDisLike = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivDisLike);

        holder.llContainerButtons = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.llContainerButtons);

        holder.llContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.llContainer);

        holder.llContainerLikeDislike = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.llContainerLikeDislike);
        holder.llContainerLikeDislike.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.llLike = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.llLike);

        holder.llDisLike = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.llDisLike);

        holder.llContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final int position2 = ((ListView) parent)
                        .getPositionForView(v);

                QA qa = getItemQa(position2);

                boolean visibility = qa.isVisible();

                if (!visibility) {

                    qa.setVisible(true);

                    UtilsLab.expand(
                            v.findViewById(R.id.llContainerLikeDislike),
                            ((ListView) parent), position2);
                } else {
                    qa.setVisible(false);

                    UtilsLab.collapse(v
                            .findViewById(R.id.llContainerLikeDislike));
                }

                QASelected selectQASelectedById = QASelectedModel
                        .selectQASelectedById(activity, qa.getId());

                if (selectQASelectedById != null) {
                    v.findViewById(R.id.llLike).setEnabled(false);
                    v.findViewById(R.id.llDisLike).setEnabled(false);

                    boolean isLike = selectQASelectedById.isLike();

                    isLike = qa.isLike();
                    qa.setWasVoted(true);

                    v.findViewById(R.id.llLike).setSelected(isLike);
                    v.findViewById(R.id.llDisLike).setSelected(!isLike);

                    ImageView ivLike = (ImageView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.ivLike);
                    ivLike.setSelected(isLike);

                    ImageView ivDisLike = (ImageView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.ivDisLike);
                    ivDisLike.setSelected(!isLike);

                    if (isLike) {
                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvAjudou))
                                .setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.app_azul_claro));

                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumLike))
                                .setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.app_azul_claro));

                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNaoAjudou))
                                .setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.app_cinza_claro));

                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumDisLike))
                                .setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.app_cinza_claro));
                    } else {
                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvAjudou))
                                .setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.app_cinza_claro));

                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumLike))
                                .setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.app_cinza_claro));

                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNaoAjudou))
                                .setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.app_vermelho));

                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumDisLike))
                                .setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.app_vermelho));
                    }
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.llLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                QA qa = getItemQa(position);

                int value = (int) (qa.getUp_count() + 1);
                qa.setUp_count(value);

                qa.setLike(true);
                qa.setWasVoted(true);

                ((LinearLayout) v).setEnabled(false);
                ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) v.getParent())
                        .findViewById(R.id.llDisLike)).setEnabled(false);
                ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivLike)).setSelected(true);
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvAjudou))
                        .setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.app_azul_claro));
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumLike))
                        .setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.app_azul_claro));

                notifyDataSetChanged();

                TrackingManager.trackEvent(ConstantsLab.VOTACAO,
                        ConstantsLab.EVENTO_RESPOSTA_POSITIVA,
                        qa.getQuestion());

                UpDownVoteWsAsyncTask asyncTask = new UpDownVoteWsAsyncTask();
                asyncTask.flagUPDown = 1;
                asyncTask.id = qa.getId();
                asyncTask.execute(ConstantsLab.WS_BASE_URL
                        + ConstantsLab.WS_UP_DOWN_VOTE);
            }
        });

        holder.llDisLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                QA qa = getItemQa(position);

                int value = (int) (qa.getDown_count() + 1);
                qa.setDown_count(value);

                qa.setLike(false);
                qa.setWasVoted(true);

                ((LinearLayout) v).setEnabled(false);
                ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) v.getParent())
                        .findViewById(R.id.llLike)).setEnabled(false);
                ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivDisLike))
                        .setSelected(true);
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNaoAjudou))
                        .setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.app_vermelho));
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumDisLike))
                        .setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.app_vermelho));

                notifyDataSetChanged();

                TrackingManager.trackEvent(ConstantsLab.VOTACAO,
                        ConstantsLab.EVENTO_RESPOSTA_NEGATIVA,
                        qa.getQuestion());

                UpDownVoteWsAsyncTask asyncTask = new UpDownVoteWsAsyncTask();
                asyncTask.flagUPDown = 0;
                asyncTask.id = qa.getId();
                asyncTask.execute(ConstantsLab.WS_BASE_URL
                        + ConstantsLab.WS_UP_DOWN_VOTE);
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final QA qa = getItemQa(position);

    if (qa != null) {

        String name = qa.getName();
        String city = qa.getCity();
        String state = qa.getState();

        if (qa.getName().equals(null) || qa.getName().equals("null")) {
            name = " ";
        }

        if (qa.getCity().equals(null) || qa.getCity().equals("null")) {
            city = " ";
        }

        if (qa.getState().equals(null) || qa.getState().equals("null")) {
            state = " ";
        }

        holder.tvLocal.setText(activity.getString(
                R.string.local_item_pergunta, name, city, state));

        holder.tvQuestion.setText(qa.getQuestion());
        holder.tvAnswer.setText(qa.getAnswer());

        holder.tvNumLike.setText(String.valueOf(qa.getUp_count()));
        holder.tvNumDisLike.setText(String.valueOf(qa.getDown_count()));

        if (qa.isVisible()) {
            holder.llContainerLikeDislike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.llContainerLikeDislike.requestLayout();
        } else {
            holder.llContainerLikeDislike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.llContainerLikeDislike.requestLayout();
        }


        if (qa.isWasVoted()) {
            holder.llLike.setEnabled(false);
            holder.llDisLike.setEnabled(false);
            verifyStatusButtonLikeDisLike(qa);
        } else {
            holder.llLike.setEnabled(true);
            holder.llDisLike.setEnabled(true);
            holder.ivLike.setSelected(false);
            holder.tvAjudou.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.app_cinza_claro));
            holder.tvNumLike.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.app_cinza_claro));
            holder.ivDisLike.setSelected(false);
            holder.tvNaoAjudou.setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.app_cinza_claro));
            holder.tvNumDisLike.setTextColor(activity.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.app_cinza_claro));
        }

    }
    return convertView;
}

private void verifyStatusButtonLikeDisLike(final QA qa) {
    if (!qa.isLike()) {
        holder.ivDisLike.setSelected(true);
        holder.tvNaoAjudou.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.app_vermelho));
        holder.tvNumDisLike.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.app_vermelho));
        holder.ivLike.setSelected(false);
        holder.tvAjudou.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.app_cinza_claro));
        holder.tvNumLike.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.app_cinza_claro));
    } else {
        holder.ivLike.setSelected(true);
        holder.tvAjudou.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.app_azul_claro));
        holder.tvNumLike.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.app_azul_claro));
        holder.ivDisLike.setSelected(false);
        holder.tvNaoAjudou.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.app_cinza_claro));
        holder.tvNumDisLike.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.app_cinza_claro));
    }
}

//another methods
//...

    /**
     * {@link AsyncTask} for the send data like or dislike.
     */
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{...}

}
```

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64639/2541) onde é explicado porque situações como esta acontecem.

Comment: Desculpe @ramaral, eu vi a resposta e não consegui entender onde estou errando ou deixando escapar a resposta.

Comment: A parte importante é compreender como funciona o mecanismo da criação das linhas e o uso do *ViewHolder*. Tem de ter em conta que a informação de uma linha é destruída quando ela deixa de estar visível. Quando é tornada novamente visível, ela terá de ser reconstruída no método `getView()`. Qualquer alteração que foi feita nela, enquanto esteve visível, terá de ser reposta na altura da sua reconstrução.

Comment: @ramaral, obrigado pela resposta. Acredito ter entendido.
Realizei alterações na classe QA para que ele guarde se esta visível ou invisível (linha do llContainerLikeDislike) e guardar o estado de votação (like e dislike) e se já foi votada (habilitar ImageViews like e dislike). Aparentemente funcionou o problema do scroll :)
Porém ao fazer testes de abrir mais de uma linha e fecha-las, o position esta vindo com valor errado e com isso esta ocorrendo comportamento errado nos eventos.

Comment: Declare os `setOnClickListener()` fora do `if(convertView == null)` após `else { holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();}`

Comment: @ramaral, funcionou! Muito obrigado!