# Como mudar a cor do item em uma listview

Tags: android, listview

Tenho  uma `listview` que é adaptada com um `SimpleCursorAdapter` e que dentro da `listview` tem dois `textview`, um com um número e outro com um nome.

Queria fazer assim... a `listview` mostra em ordem decrescente e eu queria que os 4 primeiros tivessem a cor do número azul e os quartos últimos a cor vermelha.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Teria como você adicionar alguma parte do que você já fez. Tente inserir pelo menos como está montando o SimpleCursorAdapter. Assim facilitará na obtenção de respostas mais precisas.

Comment: Relacionado(duplicata?) - [Alterar a cor Background da ListView quando o valor chave for encontrado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64605/2541), [ListView com diferentes layouts por linhas, conforme valor filtrado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272787/2541)

Comment: @ramaral parece mesmo duplicada.

Comment: nossa senhora, essa passou longe viu? aonde que ambas as questões são iguais? estamos falando aqui de mudar a cor de números ordenados, no caso mudar os quatro primeiros e os quatro últimos, e não mudar a cor de fundo de toda a lista como na outra questão. já eu estou buscando uma forma de classificá-los em um grupo, não com números, com letras, por exemplo: A verde, B rosa, C lilas e assim por diante.