# Linhas intercalando as cores android studio

Tags: android

Preciso intercalar as cores das linhas no meu aplicativo Android Studio. Tenho uma parte no meu app que traz as características do produto. Tem como criar um tipo de tabela intercalando as cores das linhas ?

Ex:
[image: Tabela Intercalando cores]

Comment: Isso é o quê? Uma ListView?

Comment: @ramaralo o exemplo que peguei acima é de um site de compras. Mas eu preciso fazer isto no meu app. Só coloquei a imagem para um melhor entendimento.

Comment: Só ajuda o entendimento se você explicar o que quer fazer. O que está na pergunta não me parece suficiente. Dá apenas para entender a questão das cores.

Comment: Sério que você não entendeu? Preciso criar uma "tabela", "listview" ou qualquer coisa que seja, intercalando as cores das mesmas

Comment: Implemente a ListView usando um Adapter personalizado e para alternar as cores das linhas veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61057/2541).

Comment: @ramaral irei tentar aqui. Você não quer colocar como uma suposta resposta o seu cometário ? Assim depois de implementar e der certo já marco como Correto sua resposta.

Comment: Se der certo é porque aquele resposta responde à sua pergunta. Nesse caso, em vez de responder, devo marcar esta pergunta como duplicada daquela.